# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7

```
When installing matplotlib 1.3.0, getting below error 

building 'matplotlib._png' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib__png_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c src/_png.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_png.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1781,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from src/_png.cpp:28:
```

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-`enter code here`packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
    src/_png.cpp: In member function ‘Py::Object _png_module::write_png(const Py::Tuple&)’:
    src/_png.cpp:147: error: ‘npy_PyFile_Dup’ was not declared in this scope
    src/_png.cpp:243: error: ‘npy_PyFile_DupClose’ was not declared in this scope
    src/_png.cpp:264: error: ‘npy_PyFile_DupClose’ was not declared in this scope
    src/_png.cpp: In member function ‘PyObject* _png_module::_read_png(const Py::Object&, bool, int)’:
    src/_png.cpp:329: error: ‘npy_PyFile_Dup’ was not declared in this scope
    src/_png.cpp:577: error: ‘npy_PyFile_DupClose’ was not declared in this scope
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

```
In other post suggested to install python-dev  and it is already installed on my server. 

Thank you in advance
Krishna
```